# Trouble Installing rpy2 on Python 3.5 osx

Tags: python, macos, python-3.5, rpy2

So I have installed rpy2 for a few different computers and I did not have trouble installing rpy2 until my attempt to install rpy2 (rpy2-2.7.8) on Python 3.5. I have a mac and for some reason it keeps failing to build the rpy2 wheel and I am not understanding the error I receive below:

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10) -- "Very Secure Dishes"
building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/JayDuck/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DHAS_READLINE=1 -I./rpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Users/JayDuck/anaconda/include/python3.5m -c ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.5/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:104:
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:6:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED;
                          ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:7:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY;
                          ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:5:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED = 0x01;
                   ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:6:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY = 0x02;
                   ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48:12: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
      SEXP res = rpy2_remove(Rf_mkString(name_buf),
           ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:125:
./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:738:13: warning: unused variable 'copy' [-Wunused-variable]
  PyObject *copy = Py_True;
            ^
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:353:3: warning: variable 'consolecallback' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
  default:
  ^~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:379:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
  if (consolecallback == NULL) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:345:24: note: initialize the variable 'consolecallback' to silence this warning
  void *consolecallback;
                       ^
                        = NULL
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:58:
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:203:44: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_IsInitialized' [-Wunused-function]
  static PyRinterface_IsInitialized_RETURN PyRinterface_IsInitialized PyRinterface_IsInitialized_PROTO;
                                           ^
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:204:38: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_FindFun' [-Wunused-function]
  static PyRinterface_FindFun_RETURN PyRinterface_FindFun PyRinterface_FindFun_PROTO;
                                     ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:128:
./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2168:1: warning: unused function 'ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp' [-Wunused-function]
ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp(PyObject *pyfloat) {
^

10 warnings generated.
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/JayDuck/anaconda/lib -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.5/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/Users/JayDuck/anaconda/lib -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.5 -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv -lr_utils -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.5/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R
ld: library not found for -lpcre
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/JayDuck/anaconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3r/n1wqjn9j5wz0z6brfp3k73sm0000gr/T/pip-build-a34prbaf/rpy2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/3r/n1wqjn9j5wz0z6brfp3k73sm0000gr/T/pip-d4_f6wpt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3r/n1wqjn9j5wz0z6brfp3k73sm0000gr/T/pip-build-a34prbaf/rpy2/
```

I have installed the latest version of R (3.2.4), Xcode, and all the usual packages to python, so I do not understand what the issue fully is during the installation process when I use "pip-install". It would be great if someone can point to me how to fix this issue and install rpy2 interface correctly. Thanks!!

Comment: You're missing libpcre (and possibly other libraries as well). Use MacPorts or Homebrew to install it.

Comment: @MattDMo The console log seems to indicate that `anaconda` is involved. May be these libraries should also handled by it ?